# Has anyone ever seen this SQL Server Error? Failed Assertion = 'm_iteratorInSafeState'. I can't find anything online to help

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We have a client running our .NET application which connects to SQL Server 2005 on the backend. A few weeks ago the database crashed and the whole server had to be rebooted.  This happened again today and I got the log file from their DBA which seriously offered no clue as to what's really going on.  I searched on Google and Bing and only found one other mention of this on a Russian programmers forum.  Given that my Russian sucks (i.e. non-existent) I decided to throw out to the geniuses on stackoverflow.  Here's the non-informative log message:

> SQL Server Assertion: File: T:\Yukon\sql\ntdbms\storeng\dfs\manager\lckmgrp.h, line=675 Failed Assertion = 'm_iteratorInSafeState'. This error may be timing-related. If the error persists after rerunning the statement, use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural integrity, or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures are not corrupted.

Any ideas?

I thank you in advance for your thoughtful replies.

Erick

Comment: You may want to post this on http://serveroverflow.com; it sounds like a hardware-related issue.

Comment: Run diagnostics on the hardware, check if you're running the most updated version of SQL Server.  If none of that works, submit the issue to Microsoft support.  Btw Stuart probably means http://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks guys.  I posted it on serverfault.  The client seems to think that this is an issue with our database and not a hardware or SQL Server instance, abut I ran the check on the database and it says everything is in line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more digging to another error that had a similar signature, I was able to determine the client needed to upgrade to Service Pack 3 since they were still on SP 1.  This was also confirmed by Microsoft support.